# How do I export a .doc and some worksheets to one PDF

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need to export a word document, together with some worksheets, via VBA to one PDF file.

I know I can export several worksheets to PDF (each worksheet is a page), but is it possible to include a .doc along with the worksheets?

Comment: Paste worksheets into Word (and size appropriately) and with this Word Doc Save As PDF

Comment: You can save .Doc as .PDF using Excel VBA. The question then becomes can you merge your sheets with this word doc? Probably, but I think it'd be easier if you opened the word doc, save as plain text, copy its contents to a sheet in your workbook, and then export your sheets to PDF as needed, or vice versa

Comment: @EricJ No to the plain text - I'd like to keep the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you build a temporary word document programmatically. 
The macro would be

1. Create new word document
2. Open the .doc
3. Copy its contents into your document
4. Instanciate Excel
5. Open each of the .xls
6. Copy their contents into your document
7. Save your document as pdf
8. Close open stuff

Digging out "how-to" for each of the operations should be simple.
Post your code when you have it, and we'll help debugging !

NB : Alternatively there are tools to merge pdf files ([Search on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=merging%20pdf%20files)). You could generate separate pdfs and then merge them. vbscript would be a suitable tool to program that  !